# Pipeline cannot infer suitable model classes from: <model_name> - HuggingFace

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

When I try to use the inference pipeline widget for my private project, I got this error.
[image]

this is seq2seq model, that receive a sentence or list of sentences and attention array for each sentence,
and return 3 classification for each char in the sentence, how can I create a pipeline for this model?

link to huggingface hub:
https://huggingface.co/NadavShaked/d_nikud23?text=My+name+is+Sarah+and+I+live+in+London

link to model and code in git:
https://github.com/NadavShaked/D_Nikud

Comment: @AnshumanKumar unfortunately not